# QtQuick 2 file size of download differ on windows

Tags: windows, qt, download, filesize, qtquick2

I wrote a small download script in the C++ part of my QtQuick2 app. This works just perfectly fine when I'm building the app for Mac OS 10.9.
For testing I download [this](http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip) file and when it's done I verify it against the given md5 check sum `b3215c06647bc550406a9c8ccc378756`

Only when I build the app on a windows PC the verification fails. On the second look I recognise that the size of the downloaded file differ with each downlaod, while the "size on disk" stays every time the same.

Do you have any idea what might trigger the strange behaviour in windows os?

Thanks in advance.

If it helps to solve the problem, I will show you my download script, but it's a pretty simple "read-all-write-to-file" script which runs every two seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could binary/text writing mode affects the result?

*UPD:* If you use `QFile` with `QIODevice::Text` it may behave differently depending on platform.

[When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum)

Comment: Thx, I tested it with a different file which is for sure binary and it worked. But can I force the binary writing mode?